# ODE solution not unique

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the solution of the initial value problem $$y'=-2\sin(x)\sqrt{y}, \quad y(0)=1, \quad y\in[0,2]$$ that are defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ are not unique.

I have found one such solution:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-2\sin(x)\sqrt{y}$$
$$y=(\cos(x)+C)^2$$
combining with the initial value yields:
$$y=(\cos(x))^2$$

Is it possible for me to find more? Is there a certain pattern here?

Comment: You are correct. There are only 2 solutions, bcoz of presence of whole square in characteristic equation.

Comment: According to my exercise there should be more. Even $y=(\cos(x)−2)^2$ shouldn't be one, since $y\in[0,2]$.

Comment: above solutions seem fine if you dont restrict y. can you share equations providd in your text?

Comment: There are no more equations. I can tell you what I had to do in the other subquestions: First I had to solve the initial value problem $y'=-2\sin(x)\sqrt{y}$. Then I had to explain why the solution is not valid for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (answer: y should be non-negative because of the square root). And finally: Show that solutions of the initial value problem that are defined for all $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ are not unique. Hint: explicitly construct two (or more) such solutions.

Comment: may be they want to reject (cosx-2)^2 bcoz its range is [1,9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given he IVP
$$y'=-2\sin (x)\>\sqrt{y},\qquad y(0)=1,$$
there is no problem with the "micro solution" defined in a small neighborhood of $x=0$: There is the unique solution $$y(x)=\cos^2(x)\qquad\left(-{\pi\over2}<x<{\pi\over2}\right)$$
you have found. It is even possible to extend this solution to all of ${\mathbb R}$. But this extension is not unique, since the basic "technical assumption" of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs is not fulfilled at the points of the $x$-axis. The function
$$y_1(x)=\left\{\eqalign{\cos^2 x\qquad&\bigl(|x|\leq{\pi\over2}\bigr) \cr 0\qquad\quad&\bigl(|x|\geq{\pi\over2}\bigr)}\right.$$
is a global solution of the given IVP as well. Since you actually have two choices for each  interval $\left(n\pi-{\pi\over2}, n\pi+{\pi\over2}\right)$, $\>n\ne0$, there are in fact uncountably many very different solutions.